# WebDriverException: unhandled inspector error - No node with given id found at a specific iteration point

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a Python script using Selenium and ChromeDriver to scrape data. The script navigates through several pages and clicks on various buttons to retrieve the data. However, I am encountering the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"No node with given id found"}
```

The error seems to occur at a specific point in the iteration, rather than being random. I have tried to troubleshoot the issue, but I am not sure what is causing it or how to fix it.

I am using `Python` 3.10.5 and the `Selenium` library with `ChromeDriver` version 113.0.5672.63 on a Windows 10 machine. Any help with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I'm still a beginner and this is my first time trying selenium. I have tried adding `time.sleep(1)` to make sure the web is loaded, check the visibility of the element, and the element is clickable but the problem still occurs.

This is the current script that I have written

```
url = '.../'
path = Service(r'...\chromedriver_win32')

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=path, options=options)
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def scrape_left_table(prob, kab, kec):
    data = [] 
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr')
    for row in rows:
        wilayah = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > button').text
        persentasi = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > span').text
        class_1= row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(2)').text
        class_2= row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(3)').text

        data.append([prob, kab, kec, wilayah, persentasi, class_1, class_2])
    
    return data

def scrape_right_table(prob, kab, kec):
    data = [] 
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr')
    for row in rows:
        wilayah = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > button').text
        persentasi = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > span').text
        class_1= row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(2)').text
        class_2= row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(3)').text

        data.append([prob, kab, kec, wilayah, persentasi, class_1, class_2])
    
    return data

data = []
 
provinsi = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr')
button = provinsi[1].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
pro = button.text
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(button)).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr')))
for i in [1,2]:
    time.sleep(1)
    kabupaten = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ') > table > tbody > tr')
    for kab in kabupaten:
        time.sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ') > table > tbody > tr')))
        kab_button = kab.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
        kab_name = kab_button.text
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", kab_button)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", kab_button)

        for i in [1,2]:
            time.sleep(1)
            kecamatan = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ') > table > tbody > tr')
            for kec in kecamatan:
                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ') > table > tbody > tr')))

                kec_button = kec.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > button')
                kec_name = kec_button.text
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", kec_button)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", kec_button)

                kelurahan = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr')
                time.sleep(1)
                left_table = scrape_left_table(pro, kab_name, kec_name)
                right_table = scrape_right_table(pro, kab_name, kec_name)
                data += left_table + right_table

                back = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.sticky-top.bg-white > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vs__actions > button')
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", back)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back)
                
        back = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div.sticky-top.bg-white > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.vs__actions > button')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", back)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back)
```

After a certain iteration i.e. for `provinsi[0]` errors occur after 689 iterations for `provinsi[1]` errors occur after 35 iterations.

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\...\web_scraping.ipynb Cell 4 in ()
     23 for kec in kecamatan:
     24     wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:nth-child(' + str(i) + ') > table > tbody > tr')))
---> 26     kec_button = kec.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.text-xs-left.wilayah-name > button')
     27     kec_name = kec_button.text
     28     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", kec_button)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"No node with given id found"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a defect with the recent ChromeDriver v113:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4440

It appears currently this is the most likely suspect:

> it happens when the element being interacted with has been determined as stale by Chromedriver

It looks like due to a defect, WebDriver is throwing a **WebDriverException** instead of **StaleElementReferenceException** (this is in C#) in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced this issue. This issue was introduced in ChromeDriver v113. It exists in v114 and v115 as well.

We have defined driver overrides to overcome this issue.

If the Chrome browser version is found to be 113, 114 or 115, we download ChromeDriver v112, the last known version to not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens only in certain DOM elements like `.gif` and alert messages from a different `iframe`. Using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` after inspecting the element helped.

Comment: Any idea when this will be fixed?